# Ubuntu Server editing file from command line

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, ssh, vim, permissions

First attempts at a linux distro.  Trying to run JeOS as a virtual machine on my mac with vmware fusion.  Installed ubuntu server 9.04 minimal virtual machine. Installed ssh. Installed VMwareTools.

Now I am trying to change permissions to a shared folder from my mac. I type in this command "sudo vi /etc/fstab" into terminal while ssh into my virtual machine.  How do I edit whatever sort of text file it brings up from the command line.  My up and down arrows just end up putting random letters in and I can't input where I want.

Basically trying to follow this guide: http://intranation.com/entries/2009/03/development-virtual-machines-os-x-using-vmware-and/

And I am at the very last steps where it tries to get read write permissions to the shared Projects folder.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Press:

- <kbd>k</kbd> to move the cursor up
- <kbd>j</kbd> to move the cursor down
- <kbd>h</kbd> to move the cursor left
- <kbd>l</kbd> to move the cursor right
- <kbd>i</kbd> to insert text
- <kbd>Esc</kbd> to be able to navigate and use other commands
- <kbd>:w</kbd> to save
- <kbd>:q</kbd> to quit
- <kbd>ZZ</kbd> or <kbd>:wq</kbd> to save *and* quit.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Ubuntu JeOS, but if it is available, you might also want to try typing 'vimtutor' at the command line for a more in-depth explanation of how to use vim/vi.

Answer (score 1):

Use nano instead of vi? nano functions like graphical text editors.

Answer (score 0):

Press the <kbd>Insert</kbd> button on your keyboard. That will allow you to navigate the file with the up/down arrow keys and type letters like normal. You can save and exit by pressing <kbd>Escape</kbd> then <kbd>:x</kbd> then <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Should be all you need.

Comment: is this possible on a macbook keyboard which has no insert key?

Comment: press         i

Comment: It's the HELP key I believe.